# How to use Curl to invoke a Temboo API?

Tags: rest, curl, temboo

How can I use curl to invoke a Temboo API? I want to get a list of all Temboo APIs.

Below is the Curl example given on a Temboo Rest API webpage. I'm not sure how to change it for correct access.

```
curl -k --basic -u user@temboo.com:test1234 --header "Accept: application/xml" --header "Content-Type: application/xml"  --header "x-temboo-domain: /myOrg/master" https://myOrg.temboolive.com:443/temboo-api/1.0/choreos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

1. Change user@temboo.com:test1234 to the email address and password on file at Temboo. e.g. toto@totomail.com:totopassword
2. Change all instances of myOrg to your Temboo account name. e.g. toto.

   curl -k --basic -u toto@totomail.com:totopassword --header "Accept: application/xml" --header "Content-Type: application/xml"  --header "x-temboo-domain: /toto/master" https://toto.temboolive.com:443/temboo-api/1.0/choreos